# Want spring bean to have mocked as well as real implementations+spring+mockito

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, spring-test

I have a class `Service` which I want to test. Basically, I am facing an issue as I want `Service` object to be partially mocked. Only `obj1` should be mocked and the rest of the other collaborators should be real ones. My code is similar to this:

```
@Component
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    Object1 obj1;

    @Autowired
    Object2 obj2;

    public void validate(){
        obj1.isValid();
        obj2.isActive();

    }
}
```

Now while testing validate method of the above `Service` class, I want to mock the o`bj1.isValid()` method while invoking real implementation of `obj2`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:conf/test-context.xml"})
public class ServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Service service;

    @Mock
    OBject1 obj1;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }


    @Test
    public void testValidate (){
        service.validate();
       //assert and other stuff
    }
}
```

This test fails and when I debugged validate method, I found that `obj1` instance is injected as mocked as expected in the `Service` class but `obj2` is injected as `null`. Hence the test fails...
Is there any way to achieve this ?

**update**
As I read in some SO answers I used springockito. I added below thing into the test class as below but still same result:

```
@ReplaceWithMock
@Autowired  
Object2 obj2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `@Autowired` annotation to `service` object so that all other attributes in `service` are injected normally and mocked objects are injected for mocked types.

In the example below, normal bean of `Class2` will be injected in `service`, but the `@InjectMocks` annotation will inject the mocked object of `Class1`.

**Service**:

```
@Component
public class Service
{
    @Autowired
    private Class1 class1;

    @Autowired
    private Class2 class2;

    public Class1 getClass1()
    {
        return class1;
    }

    public Class2 getClass2()
    {
        return class2;
    }
}
```

**Class1**:

```
@Component
public class Class1
{
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Class1";
    }
}
```

**Class2**:

```
@Component
public class Class2
{
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Class2";
    }

}
```

**Test**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({
    "classpath:application-context.xml"
})
public class ServiceTest
{
    @Mock
    private final Class1 class1 = Mockito.mock(Class1.class);

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        Mockito.when(class1.getName()).thenReturn("MockClass1");
        Assert.assertNotNull(service);
        Assert.assertEquals("MockClass1", service.getClass1().getName());
        Assert.assertNotNull("Class2", service.getClass2().getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via [@Spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html)

Your code should look like something below

```
public class ServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Service service;

    @Mock
    OBject1 obj1;

    @Spy 
    Object obj2 = new SomeObject("argument");

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but my Object2 has other autowired dependenices which I have to test so this wont be suitable to me...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is using springocito.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class,locations={"classpath:conf/test-context.xml"})

public class ServiceTest
{
    @ReplaceWithMock
    @Autowired
    private Object1 object1

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

   @Test
   public void test()
   {
   //assert stuff
   }
}
```

Service will get properly populated except Object1 which will be having mocked instance.Rest of all autowired inner beans will be populated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Autowired and InjectMocks. It's bad practise. You can use both @InjectMocks and @Spy to mock real object and to allow mocking inside this spy object

Comment: When I use spy over the  object2,it mocks the entire object.But for example obj2 has dep1 and dep2 has 2 dependencies.i want to mock only dep1.When I use Spy it mocks both of them.In that case accepted answer works.